# jquery and ajax when sending array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I made a function in jQuery that will get some data form page and then it need to send data with ajax. 
I have tested with sending some string as data and all is working fine but now , when i need to send array for some reason it does not work. 
On console i have:

```
["3"]
[]
```

And i dont get alert. Could be some problem with data types ?

```
$("#save").click(function() {
   var sendArr= new Array();
   var arr = $(".sortable").map(function(){return this.innerHTML}).get();        
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

       test =$(arr[i]).map(function() {  return $(this).attr("data-ex");    });
       console.log(test);
       sendArr[i]=test;
   }


        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/someurl/",
      data:  {action:  sendArr}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });

});
```

Comment: have you tried adding a `.fail` to see why `.done` isn't triggering?

Comment: First of all, data attributes are gotten with the `data()` method, secondly, if the data attribute is what you are after, why are'nt you mapping that instead of mapping the `innerHTML`, and then using that to get the data attribute, you're jumping thru a lot of uneccessary hoops. Finally, does your serverside scripts handle arrays, and it's not really an array once you wrap in an object before sending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gogic - make a simpler example to test with, and then build from that.

```
$(function() {

var serialized = JSON.stringify({"msg" : "Hello!"});
$.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: serialized,
    contentType: 'json',
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function(obj) {
    $('div').html(obj.msg);
}).fail(function() {
    alert('Failed!');
});

});
```

dataType is what you expect to receive; contentType is what you are sending. Your JSON has to be serialized with JSON.stringify(obj).

Also, when you send an array as a JSON, it should look like:

```
var array_json = {"myArray" : [1, "example", 2, "array"]}
var serialized = JSON.stringify(array_json)
```

Use console.log to make sure the JSON you are creating is valid.

Comment: your example works , but not with sendArr variable , if i put something like
`var jString = JSON.stringify({ action: 'test'});`
it works
when i do console.log(sendArr);
i get something like this `[["3"], []]`
mb is a problem cos that is array in a array ?

Comment: Your sendArr variable is not a valid JSON. Refer to my array_json example: {"myArray" : [1, "example", 2, "array]}. It has a key:value pair, whereas your array [["3]]" is actually an array of an array of a single string, "3". Your array makes no sense. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON before you send it in an AJAX call.